# find data attribute by part of name

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get a value of data attribute by part of name?
For example:

```
<div data-pcp-email="some text" data-pcp-order="some int" data-ref="some data"></div>
```

And suppose, I want to get all data attributes begin with `data-pcp-`: the result must be`data-pcp-email` and  `data-pcp-order`

Comment: try `$('div[data^=pcp-]')` maybe

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: @Ohgodwhy (and answerers), that would look for a `data` attribute whose value begins with `pcp-`. It doesn't seem to be what the questioner wants to achieve.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, I believe this is what he wants now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all the attributes (and their values) where the attribute name beings with 'pcp' like below:

```
// get an object map containing all data attributes
var data = $('selector').data();

// filter out what you need
for(var key in data) {
    if(key.indexOf('pcp') === 0) { // attrib names begins with 'pcp' ?
        console.log(key + ' => ' + data[key]);
    }
}
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8waUn/1/

Comment: Unfortunately, this also picks up elements that don't have `data-pcp-*` attributes if they have anything in their data that has `'pcp'` at the start of their key name: `$('<div>').data('pcpeople', 'switchToMac').appendTo('body')` would also be picked up.

Answer (score 1):

If you only set the attribute with the HTML or with jQuery `attr` function:

```
$('div[data^=pcp-]')
```

If you set the value with jQuery's `data` function, you will have to use `filter`.

```
$('div').filter(function(){
    var data = $(this).data();
    for (var key in data){
        return key.indexOf('pcp-') === 0;

    }
});
```

If you want only the attributes you can use `map`:

```
var values = $('div').map(function () {
    var data = $(this).data();
    var results = [];
    for (var key in data) {
        if (key.indexOf('pcp') === 0) results.push({
            key: key,
            value: data[key]
        });
    }
    if (results.length) 
        return results;
}).get();

console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XwjfV/)

Answer (score -2):

[Use the "attribute begins with" jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('div[data^=pcp-]')
```

Comment: This looks for elements with a `data` attribute whose _value_ starts with `pcp-`.  OP is looking for selector that matches attribute _name_ beginning with `data-pcp-`.